# Relate view & viewmodel

Tags: wpf, uiview, viewmodel

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SalesViewModel}">
     <vm:Sales>
</DataTemplate>
```

Whats the meaing of the above code in wpf resource file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `DataTemplate` associates a visual tree to a model object. This code means that when an instance of `SalesViewModel` is set as the content of a `ContentControl` (or an item in an `ItemsControl`), it will be rendered using a `Sales` control